# Real-time Changes to Google Document / Spreadsheet / Presentation

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to get a real-time notification (without extensive polling) for changes made to a Google document (document / spreadsheet / presentation)? If so, what is the model structure (if that makes sense)? Any pointers to documentation or samples would help!

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes gives an API call that returns instantly and tells you whether there have been any changes since the last one. However, this is useless you want to know almost as soon as a change has been made -- you would have to make back to back API calls every second or sooner and churn a lot of resources. The [Drive Real-time API](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/overview) in contrast gives a way to be instantly notified of any changes without extensive and frequent polling. It does this with an HTTP call that "hangs" until there is a change ready (or a timer expires). This is a classic long-poll technique.

My question is whether such a facility exists for Google Documents / Spreadsheets / Presentations. Or is it available only for custom app-specific files other than these standard ones. If it is not available, are there any plans for making them available?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my knowledge - the answer is "NO". I have tried this before and could only do it with the timed polling. The API is limited to tell you only when you ask, not when something happens.

I thought of a code that is embed into document and does a self broadcast to a specific URL or some listener. My experiments were with [Google App Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/?hl=en). Detail idea is to create a custom function that gets triggered on the 'Save' event. But I could go no further as there is nothing enough in documentation as per me to achieve this specific goal.

On the timelines for this availability, there are questions in the scripts forum on this, but none replied on these lines.

Comment: A Google employee on the Drive API team confirmed that this is not possible at present.

Comment: as of now It seems using a Google Apps Script you cant make an HTTP request (`FetchUrlApp`) in an `onEdit` event of a spreadsheet. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=185#makechanges

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it, see https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/changes
it has examples too
edit:
https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-changes
more info about tracking changes

Comment: hi, thanks, but it is not really real-time unless you waste a lot of resources to poll very frequently. i have edited the question to clarify the real-time aspect.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, I'm afraid, is no. There is currently no way for you to be notified by email when a change is made to a Drive text document. This function is available for spreadsheets, but not for text files. If your document is public, you ccan subscribe to its RSS feed to view changes, or use the Tools -> Revision History function in Drive. 
There is one downloadable program, googledocsnotifier [--information--](http://www.techaloud.com/2011/04/get-notified-of-changes-to-your-google-docs-with-google-docs-notifier/), which emails you when edits are made and allows you to open the doc that was edited, but it appears that it only works when you are online. You can [download it here.](http://code.google.com/p/googledocsnotifier/wiki/UserGuide)
Hope this helps!

Comment: on second thoughts it seems like the question may not have been clear. i am NOT looking for an email notification. i am looking for an API, almost surely an HTTP API, that does not return until a change has been made (or around a minute of time has elapsed since the call was made). additionally if a change is made it should return within a couple of seconds of the change or sooner!